# Make table for pi using C coding language

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <float.h>
int main()
{   
printf("%17.lf\n", M_PI);   
return 0;
}
```

I want to change "17" in for loop and I want to create this table (below link)

[Table image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RPr7t.png)

Comment: Note that `M_PI` is not defined by the C standard; it is however defined by POSIX.

Comment: I used to MinGW and M_PI is defined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Width and precision specifiers can be replaced by an `*`, that makes `printf` look for the value in the arguments.

```
printf("%5.3f", M_PI);
```

is equivalent to

```
printf("%*.*f", 5, 3, M_PI);
```

but now 5 and 3 can be replaced with expressions calculated at runtime.

The rest of your exercise should be trivial.

Comment: Thanks this was very helpful